# Custom Simple Contrasts R/emmeans, how to exclude comparisons

Tags: r, regression, lme4, mixed, emmeans

I'm trying to exclude contrasts from simple pairs.

Made up data:

```
library(emmeans)
library(lme4)

set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(
  dv = c(
    # Add in t1 ctrl 
      rlnorm(meanlog=0.8, sdlog=0.1, n=1000), #Long Healthy
      rlnorm(meanlog=0.7, sdlog=0.1, n=1000), #Lat Healthy
      rlnorm(meanlog=0.6, sdlog=0.1, n=500),  #Long Damaged
      rlnorm(meanlog=0.5, sdlog=0.1, n=500),  #Lat Damaged
    # Add in t2 ctrl
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.7, sdlog=0.1, n=1000), #Long Healthy
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.6, sdlog=0.1, n=1000), #Lat Healthy
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.5, sdlog=0.1, n=500),  #Long Damaged
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.4, sdlog=0.1, n=500),  #Lat Damaged
    # Add in t1 trt
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.8, sdlog=0.1, n=1000), #Long Healthy
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.7, sdlog=0.1, n=1000), #Lat Healthy
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.6, sdlog=0.15, n=500), #Long Damaged
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.5, sdlog=0.15, n=500), #Lat Damaged
    # Add in t2 trt
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.7, sdlog=0.1, n=1000), #Long Healthy
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.6, sdlog=0.1, n=1000), #Lat Healthy
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.65, sdlog=0.15, n=500),#Long Damaged
    rlnorm(meanlog=0.55, sdlog=0.15, n=500) #Lat Damaged
  ),
  id=c(rep(c("subj_1", "subj_2"), times=c(6000, 6000))),
  intervention=c(rep(c("ctrl", "trt"), times=c(6000, 6000))), 
  timepoint=c(rep(rep(c("t1", "t2"), times=c(3000, 3000)),2)), 
  direction=c(rep(rep(c("long", "lat", "long", "lat"), times=c(1000, 1000, 500, 500)),4)),
  region=c(rep(rep(c("healthy", "damaged"), times=c(2000, 1000)),4))
)
```

Model:

```
lmm_1 <- lmer(log(dv) ~ intervention*timepoint*region + direction + (1|id), data=dat)
```

emmeans reference grid:

```
lmm_1_emm <- emmeans(lmm_1, 
                     pairwise ~ intervention*region*timepoint,
                     type = "response",
                     bias.adj=TRUE,
                     sigma=sigma(lmm_1))
```

Simple pairs:

```
pairs(regrid(lmm_1_emm, 
                      bias.adjust = TRUE, 
                      sigma = sigma(lmm_1)),
      simple = "each",
      combine = TRUE)

I bet you wanted to call this with just object[[1]] - use '[[]]' or which' if I'm wrong.
See '? emm_list' for more information
 region  timepoint intervention contrast          estimate      SE  df z.ratio p.value
 damaged t1        .            ctrl - trt        -0.00263 0.06162 Inf  -0.043  1.0000
 healthy t1        .            ctrl - trt        -0.00554 0.07468 Inf  -0.074  1.0000
 damaged t2        .            ctrl - trt        -0.26043 0.06057 Inf  -4.300  0.0002
 healthy t2        .            ctrl - trt        -0.00388 0.06743 Inf  -0.057  1.0000
 .       t1        ctrl         damaged - healthy -0.37968 0.01228 Inf -30.928  <.0001
 .       t1        trt          damaged - healthy -0.38259 0.01234 Inf -31.001  <.0001
 .       t2        ctrl         damaged - healthy -0.33741 0.01099 Inf -30.691  <.0001
 .       t2        trt          damaged - healthy -0.08085 0.00814 Inf  -9.932  <.0001
 damaged .         ctrl         t1 - t2            0.16378 0.00907 Inf  18.057  <.0001
 damaged .         trt          t1 - t2           -0.09403 0.00906 Inf -10.382  <.0001
 healthy .         ctrl         t1 - t2            0.20605 0.00863 Inf  23.868  <.0001
 healthy .         trt          t1 - t2            0.20771 0.00867 Inf  23.957  <.0001

Results are averaged over some or all of the levels of: direction 
Degrees-of-freedom method: inherited from asymptotic when re-gridding 
P value adjustment: bonferroni method for 12 tests
```

How would you exclude the 4 "damaged - healthy" contrasts? I could compute the simple effects separately and leave out "region", but I like that the 'simple = "each" & combine = TRUE' options roll in the p-value correction for all the tests.

I referred to the documentation and attempted to just pull out one contrast with the following code but it failed:

```
contrast(lmm_1_emm, method = list("ctrl damaged t2" - "trt damaged t2") )

Error in "ctrl damaged t2" - "trt damaged t2" : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

p.s: What does "I bet you wanted to call this with just object[[1]] - use '[[]]' or which' if I'm wrong.
See '? emm_list' for more information" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for custom contrasts, it is always best to *not* have a left-hand side in the formula in `emmeans()`. Just get the means you want, then do the contrasts separately, e.g.,

```
emm <- emmeans(lmm_1, 
            ~ intervention * region * timepoint,
            type = "response",
            bias.adj = TRUE,
            sigma = sigma(lmm_1))
```

Second, I don't see how `contrast(lmm_1_emm, method = list("ctrl damaged t2" - "trt damaged t2") )` could have been suggested by anything in the documentation. The `method` argument needs to be a named list or the name of a contrast family.

We can see the means, and also the order in which they are presented, just by listing the object, e.g.

```
emm
```

In this example there will be 8 means listed. Then you can pick the ones you want to compare by putting `1` and `-1` in the positions in the order of listing and `0` elsewhere, e.g.,

```
contrast(emm, list(
    `t d 1 - c h 2` = c(0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    `t h 1 - t d 1` = c(0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)) )
```

This can be rather tedious, so when possible it is better to use `by` variables and named contrasts families where possible. For example, to compare successive `intervention` x `timepoint` combinations separately for each region, do

```
contrast(emm, "consec", by = "region")
```